# VBA syntax error with multiple subs on one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am attempting to create a userform with a few different scripts running in the background.

The first things I am attempting to stack right now are a combobox dropdown that hides certain columns, depending on what is selected. The second is a HasValidation check on a named range to prevent users from copy pasting over data validation in said columns.

These two pieces run fine when on separate workbooks, but the second I try and add the HasValidation to the combobox selection I get a Syntax error that I cannot for the life of my find the cause.

**My thoughts so far**

I get the syntax error when selecting ANY cell in the worksheet, so that leads me to believe I'm maybe not targeting the range correctly.

Also my Range is around 2,400 cells total so maybe I need to accommodate that with an Enable.Events = False.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("ValidationRange")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
        "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
'   Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'hide/unhide ifs. selection # = Module #
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Modify Access" Then
    Call selection_1
End If

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Remove Access" Then
    Call selection_2
End If

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Add/Update Access" Then
    Call selection_3
End If

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Team" Then
    Call selection_4
End If

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Team Change" Then
    Call selection_5
End If

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Request" Then
    Call selection_6
End If


'Initial/without a selection
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ComboBox1.Value = Null Or ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    ComboBox1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent

    Worksheets("MUS Form").Range("D:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("MUS Form").Range("T:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
ComboBox1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your HasValidation 'helper' function, change,

```
If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
```

... to,

```
HasValidation = cbool(Err.Number = 0)
```

Don't forget to reset error control and loop through the range.

```
Private Function HasValidation(rs as range) As Boolean
'   Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    dim r as range, x as long
    On Error goto err_control
    for each r in rs
        x = r.Validation.Type
    next r
    HasValidation = true
    on error goto 0
    exit function
err_control:
    HasValidation = false
    on error goto 0
End Function
```

Add event disabling to the worksheet_change so that it doesn't try to run on top of itself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("ValidationRange")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        application.enableevents = false
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
        "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
        application.enableevents = true
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. After making these changes I am now getting an "Out of Stack Space" error. I get this error when I click any cell on the sheet, not just the ValidationRange range.

Comment: @EverImmortal that's a common mistake when handling `Worksheet.Change`: by making changes to a worksheet *while handling* the `Worksheet.Change` event, you quickly enter an infinite loop of recursive calls. Disable worksheet events, make sheet changes, reinstate worksheet events. Use `Application.EnableEvents` to do that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you! I apologize if it is common, as I am quite new to excel VBA and am trying to self-teach. You've all helped teach today :)

Comment: @EverImmortal - I finally got time to seup a full sample workbook. Apparently, removing data validation via data, data validation, clear all does **not** trigger a worksheet_change event. I'm wondering if this is the best approach.

Comment: @Jeeped I appreciate the continued assistance. My main concern is copy pasting over the datavalidation formatting. Would this be sufficient to prevent that?

Comment: Then what you're doing should be adequate so long as you are aware of the limitations.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you for your help. Your example above worked well for what I need. I am going to study this to learn where I was going wrong. Do you have any suggestions for self-teaching VBA?